# How do I link two sortable lists in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rubaxa-sortable

I am using RubuXa's [Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) to create a sortable list. I am trying to link this list to another list so that when I update the sortable list (change order / delete item) the other list updates to reflect the changes.

i.e. when a user drags 'Item Heading 1' to position #2 in the Sortable List the Display List is updated to show the new positions.

**The HTML**

```
    <ul id="sortable-list">
      <li>Item Heading 1</li>
      <li>Item Heading 2</li>
      <li>Item Heading 3</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="display-list">
      <li>
        <h3>Item Heading 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Item Heading 2</h3>
        <p>Sed ullamcorper varius finibus. Cras semper libero a nibh laoreet.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Item Heading 3</h3>
        <p>Nunc tincidunt pharetra augue, non tincidunt nunc cursus vitae.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
    $(function () {
      var el = document.getElementById('sortable-list');
        var sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
        group: "name",
        store: {
            get: function (sortable) {
                var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group.name);
                return order ? order.split('|') : [];
            },
            set: function (sortable) {
                var order = sortable.toArray();
                localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group.name, order.join('|'));
            }
        },
        delay: 0,
        animation: 150
        });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnycampbell/6uy8roba/)

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @RoyDictus Sorry, I should have clarified, I am looking for some pointers as to how I can link the sortable list to the display list. I tried setting an onSort handler to the sortable list but I wasn't able to get the display list to update.

Comment: @RoyDictus The question is in the title.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. I set an onSort handler on the first list and used the dataIdAttribute option. http://jsfiddle.net/p0nft3k8/